# Label and Radio Buttons in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a satisfaction survey using the radio buttons, but not sure if my syntax are correct. This is what I did: [image: satisfaction_survey]

From what I understand, the one I am reading says each radio button should have a label, but in this case, there is no label for each radio button, because I want to align them under "Poor," "Good," "Better," and "Super."

This is how I did one of them:

```html
<div class="radio_menu">
  <p>Menu selection</p>
  <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_poor" name="menu_selection" value="poor">
  <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_good" name="menu_selection" value="good">
  <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_better" name="menu_selection" value="better">
  <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_super" name="menu_selection" value="super">
</div>
```

Is this correct?

Comment: No, labels would only make sense, if you had just one row of such radio buttons, not multiple. A label is supposed to be associated with _one_ particular form field, but that’s not the situation you have here.

Comment: Yes, you will have radio buttons without labels

Comment: (You could still add an _empty_ label around each of those input fields, to increase the click area, if you then format them to be as wide as each of your “columns” is there.)

Comment: Labels are exactly what the names say. To label an input element to tell the user what that input element is for. In your case you using a table/grid layout to label those input elements. as such no label element will be required. It is not required to use a label at all. In most cases it is just good practise.

Comment: @tacoshy The form will be inaccessible to some users without labels.

Comment: yes they ahve their advantage but its not invalid HTML to not use labels. As such it technically is allowed to not use labels. If it is good practise is a completly other story. Same storry applies to `<img>` it is a good practise to use the `alt attribute` for screen readers. However it is not required and would not be invalid HTML to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

The radio buttons do need labels to be accessible. However, they don't need to be visible if the form makes sense to sighted users without them. You can use `<span>` elements with a ["screen-reader only" class](https://gist.github.com/ffoodd/000b59f431e3e64e4ce1a24d5bb36034) within the `<label>` elements to visually hide text meant for screen readers and other assistive technologies.

Also, consider using `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` elements to group form fields.

This could look like:

```html
<fieldset class="radio_menu">
  <legend>Menu selection</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_poor" name="menu_selection" value="poor">
    <span class="sr-only">Poor</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_good" name="menu_selection" value="good">
    <span class="sr-only">Good</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_better" name="menu_selection" value="better">
    <span class="sr-only">Better</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="menu_selection_super" name="menu_selection" value="super">
    <span class="sr-only">Super</span>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```